# Refresh div without layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, refresh

i want to refresh a div without layout page only div. 
  The problem is layout doesnt refresh but i cant access the other tabs because all of page is refreshing.So how can i refresh only div=IsEmri? 
    Thanks a lot.
Here is the code:

```js
<script src="~/js/jquery_1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = location.pathname=$('#IsEmri').replace(/&?_layout=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //    $('#IsEmri').load(url);
    //});
    function refresh() {

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#IsEmri').fadeOut('slow').load(url).fadeIn('slow');
            refresh();

        }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row col-md-12" id="IsEmri">
        @foreach (var item in Model.IsEmirleri)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm col-4">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> @await Component.InvokeAsync("IsEmri", item)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: You should share the html markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = location.pathname=$('#IsEmri').replace(/&?_layout=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('#IsEmri').hide();
           refresh();
        }, 5000)
    });

    function refresh() {       
        $('#IsEmri').show().fadeOut('slow').load(url).fadeIn('slow');
    }
</script>
```

Wait for your DOM to be ready, when it is, initiate a timer which calls the setInterval after a specified period again and again.